# Replacing a character from standard output on the fly

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, pipe

I'm not sure this is possible, but I'm trying to replace a character from standard output on the fly.

The issue is like this. A command *c1* produces the output
So, `c1 | less` gives me `ABC`

I would like to replace occurrences of `B` with `D`, so I get `ADC`.

If possible that my command chain should be something like

```
c1 | <something> | less
```

and print `ADC` instead of `ABC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use sed:

```
c1 | sed 's/B/D/' |less
```

For the given example of replacing "ABC" with "ADC".
If you want to replace all occurrences of B on D use the option g (global)

```
sed 's/B/D/g'
```

You can find more using:

```
man sed
```

Comment: Work fine! Any chance this would work for Unicode characters? :) e.g. \u0091

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean. Can you show a specific string (several characters) with the 0x91 character? At the sed terminal, I can easily change the \ u0091 character.